# Bootstrap - fit parent height to child/content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

on this link: [testing v1](http://colorfill.nstrefa.pl/clients/testing/)

you can find an example page which I've created in bootstrap. Nothing hard but i have a tiny issue with parent and child relation. As you see, the content breaks the parent size. And im just wondering why as I used in all classes height&min-height 100%. Any ideas?

Comment: `/* height: 100%!important; */`

Comment: I've removed it but it wasn't the case. Issue still appears.

Comment: You want the parent to fit the child's content or you want a scholl bar?

Comment: yes i want the parent to fit the child. currently child breaks the parent, what is strange..

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: The issue as I understand it is resolved if I remove that line--the container element stretches to contain the text. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what is making the `.col-lg-6.sidebar` have less height than its child ( `.testowo` ) is the `height: 100%`.

```
.sidebar {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F00;
    background-image: url("../images/background.png");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-size: inherit;
    /* height: 100%; */ //remove this line
    min-height: 100%;
```

If you want the parent have the height adjusted to its child's content don't set its height. You may think it still breaks but no, it is just the `background-image` used that will be centered. The height of the parent will adjust depending on the child's content.

What is happening is that all the `div`s have `height: 100%` So it goes like this:

`html` --> its initial height is the height of your browser window.

`body` --> `height: 100%` make its height be the `htmls`'s height that is your browser's window height.

`.main-part` --> `height: 100%` makes its height be `body`'s height. The same, it will be your browser's window height.

`.container-fluid` --> `height: 100%`, the same as `body` and `.main-part`.

`.row` --> `height: 100%`, the same as `body`, `.main-part` and `.container-fluid`.

`.col-lg-6.sidebar` --> `height: 100%`, the same. So it will be your browser's window height and the content will break it. You are setting a fixed height here, it is 100% but if you scalate you will notifice by giving `height: 100%` you are setting the height equal to `html`'s height therefore you browser's window height. Let it adjust to its content by removing the `height:100%` declaration or setting `height: auto`.

Also you don't need to set `height: 100%` in `.testowo`. It makes no difference.

```
.testowo {
    width: 200px !important;
    position: relative;
    /* height: 100%; */ //remove this since it is useless.
}
```

NOTE: Remember, when working with `%` values in your CSS it makes reference to the parent, not the child. Setting `height: 100%` to an element will make the height equal to its parent's height, not the child's. Use `height: auto` for it to adjust to its content.

Comment: thank you so much for this clarifiaction. I still have so much to learn!

Comment: You are welcome. Remember `height: 100%` makes the height be equal to it's parent height, no the child's :)